# Aligment in pdfBox acroForm Text field when field markd as "Split by N symbols"

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Objective: fill out a PDF form in which the characters must be inscribed in the squares (Using pdfBox 2.0.24). Therefore, there is a sign “divide into N characters” in the fields.

[template.pdf](https://azovkomeks.ru/pdf/test.pdf)

Problem: horizontal alignment doesn't work. If you open the template in any viewer, then you will be able to enter information with your hands and it will be displayed correctly.
but after filling from the program - alignment doesn't work [filled-form.pdf](https://azovkomeks.ru/pdf/resp.pdf)

Some screenshots:

> In viewer:
>  [image: screenshotInViewer]

> After filling form from programm:
>  [image: screenshotAfterProgram]

An example that will repeat the problem:

[template.pdf](https://azovkomeks.ru/pdf/test.pdf)

code:

```
public static byte[] testFillPdf(byte[] pdf, Map<String,String> data) throws Exception{
    PDDocument inDoc = PDDocument.load(pdf);

    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = inDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    acroForm.setXFA(null);
    acroForm.setNeedAppearances(false);

    PDTextField field1 = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("field1");
    field1.setValue("1");
    PDTextField field2 = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("field2");
    field2.setValue("2");

    acroForm.refreshAppearances();
    acroForm.flatten();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inDoc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    inDoc.save(baos);
    inDoc.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

I could not find a solution to this problem. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I assume that by *horizontal alignment doesn't work* you mean that the lower field appears not to respect the right alignment. Indeed, apparently PDFBox ignores the quadding for fields with the **comb** flag.

Comment: @mkl I assume that by horizontal alignment doesn't work you mean that the lower field appears not to respect the right alignment. - yes (i'm not good in English, sorry)

Comment: @mkl Sorry, but I not completely understand your phrase "Indeed, apparently PDFBox ignores the quadding for fields with the comb flag"... Its assumption or fact?

Comment: After looking at the code, I see it's a TODO.

Comment: @torchinsky *Sorry, but I not completely understand your phrase "Indeed, apparently PDFBox ignores the quadding for fields with the comb flag"... Its assumption or fact?* - I checked your PDF and found no error there. Your code looks ok. Thus, I concluded that PDFBox ignores the quadding on comb fields. As Tilman meanwhile commented, the PDFBox code indeed is unfinished here.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5256

Comment: @TilmanHausherr - thanks. I have tried find some issue on tracker, but i don't know what isComb - flag that i used.

Comment: About the comb flag: "If  set,  the  field  shall  be  automatically  
divided  into  as  many  equally  spaced  positions,  or  combs,  as  the  
value of MaxLen, and the text is laid out into those combs." https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf in Table 228 on page 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tilman Hausherr - "After looking at the code, I see it's a TODO. [issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5256](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5256)"

Comment: I've added the enhancement to support the alignment for comb fields so it should be available in PDFBox 2.0.25 and 3.0.0 once they are released.  You might want to check using a snapshot build or wait for the release(s). Release dates have not been set yet.

Comment: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.25-SNAPSHOT/